# Select all data from multiple table ON same field value

Tags: mysql, join, union, multiple-tables

This is my database tables look like :

regular_employee :

```
+----+---------------+-----------------+-----------+----------------+
| id | employee_name | employee_job    | join_date | permanent_date |
+----+---------------+-----------------+-----------+----------------+
|  1 | ZELDA         | ACCOUNTANT      | 2020/02   | 2020/03        |
|  2 | YUGO          | QA              | 2020/02   | 2020/04        |
|  3 | XAVIER        | GENERAL MANAGER | 2020/02   | 2020/05        |
|  4 | WAVY          | FACTORY MANAGER | 2020/01   | 2020/02        |
+----+---------------+-----------------+-----------+----------------+
```

contract_employee :

```
+----+---------------+--------------+-----------+
| id | employee_name | employee_job | join_date |
+----+---------------+--------------+-----------+
|  1 | ANTONIO       | ACCOUNTANT   | 2020/01   |
|  2 | BAGGIO        | ENGINEER     | 2020/02   |
|  3 | CHARLES       | QA           | 2020/02   |
|  4 | DAVID         | QA           | 2020/02   |
+----+---------------+--------------+-----------+
```

**My Goal :**
Select all employee_job who joined the company on 2020/02 and distinct / group them by employee_job

What i've tried :

```
SELECT re.employee_job,ce.employee_job 
FROM regular_employee AS re,contract_employee AS ce 
WHERE re.join_date = '2020/02' AND ce.join_date = '2020/02' 
GROUP BY re.employee_job,ce.employee_job
```

The result was :

```
+-----------------+--------------+
| employee_job    | employee_job |
+-----------------+--------------+
| ACCOUNTANT      | ENGINEER     |
| ACCOUNTANT      | QA           |
| GENERAL MANAGER | ENGINEER     |
| GENERAL MANAGER | QA           |
| QA              | ENGINEER     |
| QA              | QA           |
+-----------------+--------------+
```

What i was expecting :

```
+-----------------+
| employee_job    |
+-----------------+
| ACCOUNTANT      |
| ENGINEER        |
| GENERAL MANAGER |
| QA              |
+-----------------+
```

How to do this query ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A union query might make more sense here:

```
SELECT employee_job FROM regular_employee WHERE join_date = '2020/02'
UNION
SELECT employee_job FROM contract_employee WHERE join_date = '2020/02';
```

`UNION` by default will remove duplicate jobs which might appear in one/both of the two tables.

Comment: this is exactly what i was lookig for, thanks for the help man, but, i was wondering why this works perfectly, while those two tables have different number of field ?

Comment: @owf `UNION` removes all duplicates, this is why you get the distinct output you expect.